# Does this Decorator implementation violate the Liskov Substitution Principle?

Tags: design, design-patterns, object-oriented, solid, liskov-substitution

Please consider the following implementation of the Decorator design pattern:

`WordBank` objects store strings and return them to the client through the method `getWords()`.

The decorator class, `WordSorter`, is a subclass of `WordBank` (as in the Decorator pattern). However it's implementation of `getWords()` sorts some of the strings and removes them, before returning the array to the client.

For example a `WordSorter` might delete all of the strings in the bank that start with letter 'a', and only after that return the array to the client.

Does this violate the [Liskov Substitution Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle)? Since some implementations of `WordBank` return strings while others first sort through the strings and only return some of them, I'm not sure if it's safe to say that a `WordSorter` can be used anywhere any other `WordBank` is used. Or am I understanding this principle wrong?

[image]

Comment: I don't believe there is a change in the "behavior" of the program if there is only a change in the values offered.

Comment: @BobDalgleish Nearly everything interesting about a program's behavior revolves around the data it handles. Output routines need to be fed data, computations turn data into other data, control flow can depend heavily on data, and once you leave the cozy warmth of structured programming, even code itself (or at least behavior in the form of polymorphism) is data. When a `List<int>` starts ignoring the data put into it and instead always contains 17 copies of the number 42, every nontrivial program using `List<int>` goes haywire.

Comment: @delnan You have completely ignored the point of both the question and LSP. WordSorter may safely be substituted for WordBank because there is no change in the behavior.

Comment: @BobDalgleish Read my answer for what I have to say on LSP and the question. My point towards you is that the data offered may or may not count as a change of behavior, depending on what constraints the supertype sets on the values offered.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A `WordSorter` **is-a** `WordBank`, so code that works with a `WordBank` should also work when a `WordSorter` is used instead of a `WorkBank`. On the other hand, a `WordSorter` **is-not-a** `SomeWordBank`. The compiler won't even let you use a `WordSorter` in place of a `SomeWordBank`, so the issue does not even begin to arise.

There *might* be a LSP violation, but doesn't appear to be from the minimal specification you've given. Does `WordSorter` guarantee, for example, that one can add arbitrary strings to it and retrieve them all in the same order later? Then sorting the words would indeed break the that contract, and code that works for "correct" `WordBank`s can be broken by substituting a `WordSorter`. Whether there is such a guarantee is impossible to tell from the minimal UML diagram you've shown. If, for example, `WordBank`'s contract says all words which are added are included in the result of `getWords`, then:

```
bank.add(w);
AssertContains(bank.getWords(), w);
```

should always work. That code would break if `bank` was a `WordSorter`, and it's `WordSorter`'s fault for breaking the contract and hence violating the LSP. But if `WordBank` offers no such guarantee, then the above code is in the wrong (in the same way `asser x*y == 42` will usually fail) and `WordSorter` is a perfectly well-behaved subclass.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I think that what I'm asking is this: Say you have a `WordBank` instance and a `WordSorter` instance. They are both fed the same array of strings. In this case, these two lines of code: `wordBank.getWords()` and `wordSorter.getWords()` - return different data. I guess that my question is: a `WordSorter` will return different data than a `WordBank`. The data will be of the same type, and the method signatures are the same - so no compile error will occur by substituting a `WordBank` with a `WordSorter`. But the data is different. Is this a violation of LSP?

Comment: @Prog Again, it completely depends on the contract of `WordBank`. The sole fact that it returns different data (assuming `WordBank` wasn't abstract) is not a problem. It would be quite silly to mandate that subtypes are *identical*. They only must be *compatible* and what's compatible depends entirely on what you're doing. It's up to the person defining `WordBank`. If they say a `WordBank` returns the same words in the same order, it's an LSP violation. If they say a `WordBank` returns a subset of the word in arbitrary order, then it's fine. It's a weaker contract but a valid and useful one.

Comment: I see. So it depends on what `getWords()` in `WordBank` was supposed to do in the first place. If it's meant to 'return all of the strings it contains', than there's an LSP violation. But if it's meant to 'return part of the strings it contains', then it's not an LSP violation since this contract is fulfilled both with WordBank and WordSorter. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: @Prog Yes, that sounds good. I also added an example to the answer.

Comment: And also: if the 'contract' of `getWords()` in `WordBank` is "do some or no sorting of strings, and return the resulting list of strings", but the client code was using `getWords()` while assuming it meant "always return all the strings", the code *will* break when subsituting with a `WordSorter` - *but that's the client code's fault, not `WordSorter`'s fault.* Right?

Comment: @Prog Absolutely (if by "return all the strings" you mean *in the same order*). The client code was either too accepting (too broad, too liberal) by asking for a `WordBank` (perhaps there is some subtype which *does* guarantee original order), or it misread the contract. Either way it's a problem with the client code and need to be fixed there.

Answer (score 1):

By the general description given, it sounds as though the concrete types `WordBank` and `WordSorter` (might be better called `WordFilter`) should be separate types both implement from a common interface `IWordSource`, and/or inherit from a common abstract base class `WordSourceBase` which does so, rather than having either concrete type inherit from the other (setting aside the question of what it should mean when a method returns an array).  Code which wants to be able to store things into a word holder and know that items will be returned in the order supplied should demand a `WordBank`.  Code that wants something that can supply a list of words, but doesn't care how that list is produced should demand an `IWordSource`.  Code that wants something that can be given to code that expects an `IWordSource` but filters the supplied data first should create a `WordSorter`/`WordFilter`.

While I would not go so far as to suggest that instantiable classes should always be sealed, I would suggest that many situations where one might consider inheriting from an instantiable class would be better handled by having the original instantiable class inherit from an abstract base, and having the proposed derivative type also inherit from that same base.  Code which is concerned about precise details of how the original instantiable class works (which might be different in the derived type) can demand a reference of that type, while code which is only interested in the abstract behaviors can accept a reference of that base type (which could then identify either the original type or a derivative).

Comment: Your last paragraph there might be the clearest explanation of the open/closed principle I've seen for a while. +1 for linking it to a good, concrete situation where it shows a real improvement in the code.

Comment: @Jules: One annoyance I have in Java and .NET is that the only construct for creating objects requires that the code invoking it specify the exact type to be created.  While there are some situations where it's nice that `new Foo()` is guaranteed to return a reference to an instance of `Foo` to which no reference previously existed, there are many times when it would be nice to have an expression that makes clear its result type but is non-specific as to whether its exact type will be `Foo` or a derivative, or--for immutable types--whether the object will necessarily be new.

Comment: @Jules: IMHO, the normal pattern for object creation should be to call a factory method which then constructs an instance of its own type, but there's no way of knowing whether `SomeType.someMethod()` returns a type which has any relation whatsoever to `SomeType`.  It would be nice if there were a means of invoking a static method which would make clear that the return type is the class upon which it is being invoked (and, in .NET, if interfaces could sport such static methods).

Answer (score -2):

Yes.  Liskov is angry.  But we can survive.  The larger impact won't be felt until a couple more levels of magnitude of complexity are built upon these patterns.  And even then it will be measured in lost time and efficiency.  It will be felt in the negative space of what we can do with our minds given limited time upon this earth.  In other words, nobody is gonna call you on it.....